# XPath - Get just some part of the attribute value or text node

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Well, I have the following html that I want to get the `@data-coords` attribute from, but I want the latitude and longitude to be in different variables. See html bellow:

```html
<div id="gmap-container">
    <div id="gmap-value" data-coords="-26.995548880319042,-48.633818457672135,16,150">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

If I use `//div[@id='gmap-imovel']/@data-coords` as XPath, it returns the entire thing from `@data-coords` attribute.

My Python code is something like that:

```py
xpaths = {
    "parser_lat": "//div[@id='gmap-value']/@data-coords", 
    "parser_lon": "//div[@id='gmap-value']/@data-coords"
}

latitude: str = parsel.Selector().xpath(xpaths['parser_lat']).extract_first()
longitude: str = parsel.Selector().xpath(xpaths['parser_lon']).extract_first()

return latitude, longitude
```

I would like to get the latitude and longitude splitted as mentioned above, I know that I can add regular expression to the Python code to get what I want, but that way would break the pipe for others websites. Example using regular expression that I don't want to use:

```py
regex_expression = r'^-(\d+\.\d+)'

latitude = re.findall(regex_expression, '-26.995548880319042,-48.633818457672135,16,150')[0]
longitude = re.findall(regex_expression, '-26.995548880319042,-48.633818457672135,16,150')[1]
```

This example above would give me the `-26.995548880319042` and `-48.633818457672135` in their respective variables, but as I mentioned this will break the pipe to other websites.

I want to get this result I mentioned above only using XPath, like this:

```
parser_lat: regex('^-(\d+\.\d+)', //div[@id='gmap-imovel']/@data-coords)[0]
parser_lon: regex('^-(\d+\.\d+)', //div[@id='gmap-imovel']/@data-coords)[1]
```

and then use it in the first Python code example I gave.

I tried using `substring` but didn't worked for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "without changing my code"? Obviously, you have to change **something** to fix it. Can you edit your question, include the complete code used and indicate the parts which can and can't change?

Comment: I just edited the question with a more detailed thought of what I want, hope you understand it. My complete code is too big to post here, but the first code example is basically the same. I'll post here my GitHub repository if you want to have a better look at it. Repository: github.com/jakoritarleite/datareal-crawler
The part of the code you want to see is in `lib/models/crawl.py` on the `_Scrape` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`substring-before()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-substring-before) and [`substring-after()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-substring-after) in your XPaths...

```py
xpaths = {
    "parser_lat": "substring-before(//div[@id='gmap-value']/@data-coords, ',')", 
    "parser_lon": "substring-after(//div[@id='gmap-value']/@data-coords, ',')"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I tried using substring-before but didn't worked, probably I did something wrong before. The `parser_lat` is the same as the one you shared, but I needed to change the `parser_lon` since there's more 2 commas at the end of the value that doesn't correspond to the longitude. The `parser_lon` is now: `substring-before(substring-after(//div[@id='gmap-value']/@data-coords, ','), ',')` Thanks mate